# How do I cancel a time-delayed  screenshot?

Tags: gnome, command-line, bash, screenshot

I'm using the default screenshot application that comes with Ubuntu `gnome-screenshot`

When I was using it earlier to take screenshots of the lock screen I had set a long time delay, but forgot to change it back after I'd finished. When I next took a timed screenshot I had to wait a long time for it to take because the delay was still set so long.

Clicking the icon to relaunch the screenshot application has no effect whilst the timer is in effect, I imagine there is probably a simple terminal command to shut down an application, but I don't know it! Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Total guess but 'gnome-screenshot --quit' in terminal?

Comment: @TomBrossman this gives an interesting output of `** (gnome-screenshot:23565): CRITICAL **: Unable to parse arguments: Unknown option --quit
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one-liner you're looking for is:

```
kill `pidof gnome-screenshot`
```

> *pidof* is preferable here compared to `pgrep`, `killall` and some invocations of `ps`, which only consider the first 15 characters of a command name and can choke on hyphens. Be careful not to kill the similarly prefixed `gnome-screensaver` if you use these..

Answer (score -2):

**Step1.** Looking for the process numbers of gnome-screenshot by `ps ax` command in the terminal.

**Step2.** Execute `kill <process_number>`.

**Step3.** Insert the following command from the terminal:

```
gnome-screenshot -i
```

Then, you can set **Grab after a delay** 0 second.

Comment: The question asked how to cancel a screenshot, this command just launches the application